# CV in ConTeXt, correspondence - moderncv

Tags: context, moderncv, cv, examples

How should a minimal example of a CV look when written using the `moderncv` interface from the `correspondence` module?

I'm still a bit confused about modules and interfaces so some hints on how to check my environment including everything I need for this would be nice too (I'm using TeX Live 2010 on Gentoo Linux, no problems with rendering simple documents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `moderncv` package comes with a directory of [examples](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples) that show how the code is supposed to look.

For example this [template](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex) should compile and show you how things ought to work.

If you have an older version of the package, the `\email` command might not work (and you have to comment it out to get it to compile.)